# Update url_title when editing similar to when creating a new entry in a channel

Tags: control-panel

We recently updated an old site from EE 2 to EE 5.  In EE 2 when you edited a title of an entry it would also update the url title the same way that it does when you create one.  Now on EE 5 it will not update the url title if you are editing an entry.  It will only do that when you create an entry.  I get the reasoning for this as if an entry is published and you change the url of that entry it could cause problems but the admins for this site are requesting that functionality back as that is what they are accustomed to.

I know the functionality is already there as it does it when you create an entry and wondering if there is any way to trigger this when you edit an entry.  If not are there any open source plugins to add javascript to the admin control panel.

Comment: I've been using EE since version 1.6 and have never seen that behaviour. Once an entry+url_title is saved it shouldn't automatically change when you edit the Title. Were you using an addon that overwrites default behaviour?

Comment: I've also never seen this behavior. EE just creates a URL Title based on the Title when you initially make the entry.

Comment: Honestly I am not sure either but the admins who have been using the EE v2 for the last X years claim that to be the case.  I solved it for them by creating a plugin to add some javascript to update url_title on keyup of title text input.